# Openstack4j osclient Identity API V2 create or update returns null

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Using openstack4j osclient Identity API V2 create or update tenant or user unsucessfully, it returns null

```
OSClientV2 os = OSFactory.builderV2()
             .endpoint("http://ip:port/v2.0")
             .credentials(username,password)
             .tenantName(projectName)
             .authenticate();
os.identity().tenants().create(Builders.identityV2().tenant().name("TOKENSD")
             .description("测试API").build());
```

It only returns null, how  can I solve this problem ?